# Should there be a separate tag for videos?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes there are questions about videos, movies, documentaries, etc. (I'll add a small sample below.)

Would it be useful to have a separate tag for this topic? This could possibly help when searching for such questions.

Or would such tag be too specific to be actually useful?

Some of those questions are tagged [online-resources](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/online-resources). This tag is a good fit at least in some cases. But not every video is automatically online.

I will add also link to a similar discussion on Mathematics Meta: [Tag for (videos)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15169) (Of course, I am fully aware that these are two completely separate sites and tagging systems on the two sites are different.)

---

Here are examples of some questions about this topic - I have tried to choose some of highly voted question and some of relatively recent questions. (Basically the fact that I wasn't sure what would be good choice of tags of a recent question about videos from ICM 2018 was the reason that I've posted this question.)

- [Best online mathematics videos?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/1714)
- [Video lectures of mathematics courses available online for free](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54430)
- [(Preferably rare) Audio/Video recordings of famous mathematicians?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/58554)
- [Video lectures for Algebraic Geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/q/78037)
- [Interesting mathematical documentaries](https://mathoverflow.net/q/100033)
- [Online high quality colloquium talks](https://mathoverflow.net/q/139312)
- [Are there any organized websites for seminar/conference videos?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/169266)
- [ICM 2018 lecture videos](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307482)

Comment: Videos are not an area in mathematics -- so this would be a meta-tag like reference-request. As I understand, the number of meta-tags should be limited.

Comment: @StefanKohl Would you be willing to expand your comment a bit and post it as an answer? I think that if there is an answer there is more chance to get some feedback from other users. (If nothing else, at least users can upvote/downvote and the answer is definitely more visible than a comment. Of course, the same goes for the other question of mine where you recently commented.) In any case, thanks for the comment - and, possibly, thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: @StefanKohl I have posted a CW answer summarizing your two comments. I hope I understood them correctly - if not, feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a CW-answer to summarize objections *against* creating a separate tag for this topic which were made in the comments (so that other users can upvote/downvote, comment, etc.):

- The tag for videos would be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), i.e., it does not specify area of mathematics and content of the question, rather it gives a type of question (similar to [reference-request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/reference-request) or [soft-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/soft-question)). Although some meta tags are tolerated, it's better not too have too many of them.
- The tag is possibly too specialized - there are only 5 slots for tags, if there are too many very specialized tag it would be difficult to tag questions correctly.